# HtmlUnit Get Title of HtmlAnchor

Tags: htmlunit

I don't see this method in the documentation, http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlAnchor.html

Is there a way to get the Title attribute from an HtmlAnchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I wanted shortly after posting this question (through trial and error):

```
anchor.getAttribute("title")
```